# Getting "stack level too deep" error when deploying with Capistrano, Rails 3.1 ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, asset-pipeline

Here is the log for the cap deploy script output around where the error occurs. Anny suggestions why this might be happening? Thanks!

```
    [yup.la] executing command
    [yup.la] sh -c 'cd /srv/www/portrait/releases/20120406051647 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'
 ** [out :: yup.la] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: yup.la] 
 ** [out :: yup.la] stack level too deep
 ** [out :: yup.la] (in /srv/www/portrait/releases/20120406051647/app/assets/stylesheets/mobile.css.scss)
 ** [out :: yup.la] 
 ** [out :: yup.la] Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
 ** [out :: yup.la] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 ** [out :: yup.la] 
    command finished in 30868ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /srv/www/portrait/releases/20120406051647; true"
    servers: ["yup.la"]
    [yup.la] executing command
    [yup.la] sh -c 'rm -rf /srv/www/portrait/releases/20120406051647; true'
    command finished in 288ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /srv/www/portrait/releases/20120406051647 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on yup.la
/Users/victorstan/Sites/portrait ∴
```

Comment: Does `bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile` work fine locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your sass-rails version from 3.1.5 to 3.1.4 in your Gemfile.

Comment: This is the issue causing error: [#78 issue](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/78)

Comment: But I cant install it with rails 4.2.1. sass-rails '3.1.4'. how to fix that?

Comment: @Santanu Sorry for reply late, is ur problem has been fixed?

Comment: Actually I forgot, I hope it was fixed, but I forget the project name as there are multiple.

Comment: @Santanu hahaha okay, hope those projects are fixed ;)